# Physical explanation: why don't pressure gradients form in gravitational flow down a semi-infinite vertical tube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

Previous answers here to the question of pressure gradients created during liquid flow down a skinny (low Re) vertical tube are:
a) [Liquid flow in a vertical tube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250004/liquid-flow-in-a-vertical-tube)
and
b) [Friction loss in a vertical pipe flow](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270882/friction-loss-in-a-vertical-pipe-flow)

These nice previous posts don't provide a "phenomenological" physical answer to the question of why pressure remains homogeneous (i.e. dP/dz = 0 everywhere) in the vertical tube. In the case of (a) the discussion incorrectly uses Bernoulli's Principle which is explicitly only for inviscid flows.  In the case of (b) the leading answer from Chet Miller (using Darcy–Weisbach equation) is derived very nicely and rigorously up until the equation

$$\frac{d(P + \rho gz)}{dz}=\frac{f}{D}\frac{\rho v^2}{2}$$

and then after that equation the dP/dz is back-calculated to be zero for a vertical pipe but I don't see any "phenomenological" physical explanation of why dP/dz = 0. What "F = ma" cause-effect physical reason is there for dP/dz to be zero at all locations within the tube?

Comment: @ChetMiller is active daily on the site; if you have a question about one of the terms of his derivation, try posting a comment to his answer to get clarification.

Comment: I tried to do exactly that.  Stackexchange blocked me from posting a comment directly on Chet's derivation because I "don't have a stackexchange reputation of 50 or higher".

Comment: Maybe you have overlooked the description "For a horizontal tube" between the second last and last equation, which you refer to. I think that explains it pretty well? And also it shows that in fact, gravity does not drop out..

Comment: Aha thank you @AtmosphericPrisonEscape.  You're correct but my main point still stands.  I reworded the question to resolve the error you pointed out.

Comment: Is this a liquid without yeast in it so there will be no gas bubbles and so on ?

Comment: Also is it in steady state so it will not change phase? (semi-infinite is a pretty big pipe...)

Comment: Hi Damon, I just re-edited below to provide a completely different answer. Please consider checking it out when you get a sec. thanks for the question have a good night.

Comment: Also i’ll comment to chet for you.

Answer (score 0):

If we do a force balance on the fluid within the section of the tube between z and z + $\Delta z$, where z is measured upward, we get $$P(z+\Delta z)\pi \frac{D^2}{4}-P(z)\pi \frac{D^2}{4}+(\rho g\Delta z)\pi \frac{D^2}{4}=\tau_W\pi D\Delta z$$where $\tau_w$ is the upward viscous shear stress exerted by the wall on the fluid, and the 3rd term on the LHS is the weight of the fluid in the interval between z and z + $\Delta z$.  Taking the limit as $\Delta z$ approaches zero, we obtain:  $$\frac{dP}{dz}+\rho g =\frac{4}{D}\tau_w$$If we integrate this equation between z = 0 (the bottom of the tube where $P = p_{atm}$) and z = L (the top of the tube where, again, $P = p_{atm}$), we obtain $$\rho g =\frac{4}{D}\tau_w$$The LHS of this equation is the weight per unit volume of the liquid in the tube, and the RHS is the viscous frictional force of the wall per unit volume of the liquid in the tube.

Of course, you can apply a higher pressure at the bottom than at the top, causing a lower flow rate and wall shear stress, or apply a higher pressure at the top than at the bottom, causing a higher flow rate and wall shear stress.  But, in all cases, the weight of the fluid helps to lower the pressure difference needed to maintain a desired flow rate.

Compressibilty has nothing to do with this.

For laminar flow of a viscous fluid, the shear stress at the wall is given by:  $$\tau_w=\mu\frac{32Q}{\pi D^3}$$where Q is the downward volumetric flow rate and $\mu$ is the fluid viscosity.  So for the general case where we have arbitrary pressures at the two ends of the tube, we have $$P(L)-P(0)=\mu\frac{128QL}{\pi D^4}-\rho gL$$

Comment: You cannot "integrate this equation" between z = 0 and z = L if you don't already know the pressure profile.  The whole point of this post is that we don't know the profile of pressure (or the profile of the pressure gradient). Therefore you cannot rigorously move from the $\frac{dP}{dz}+\rho g =\frac{4}{D}\tau_w$ equation to the $\rho g =\frac{4}{D}\tau_w$ equation via integration.  That integral is unknown, given the a priori information at hand.

Comment: Of course I can integrate.  This equation follows directly from the solution to the Navier Stokes equations, which reveal all the characteristics of the pressure variation we need.   I guess you are not familiar with the Navier Stokes equations or how to solve them?

Comment: I'm familiar with Navier-Stokes. Let me reword: you can't integrate dP/dz between one of the boundaries and an interior non-boundary location z because you don't have an explicit equation for dP/dz. You can only integrate functions for which you have an explicit equation.

This point gets much stronger if you make the vertical tube become semi-infinitely tall.

So let's re-ask the question: For fluid in a semi-infinite vertical pipe driven by a uniform body force (e.g. a uniform gravitational field if it were physically possible), derive the velocity in the pipe?  Your derivation breaks.

Comment: Oh yeah? Well let’s see your approach to solving the NS equations for steady flow through a vertical tube.

Comment: Lemme guess.  You're not an engineer?  You're a mathematician?

Comment: How come the only approximation you are attacking is that the fluid is incompressible.  Why not the effect of elevation on g?  Or the effect of the phases of Jupiter's moons on g?  Or the effect of viscous heating on temperature?  Or the effects of tube roughness on the flow?

Comment: I've picked this problem because I'm building a molecular model and need to understand the physical regimes in which a fluid can be considered "incompressible".  My model will be incorrect if I assume incompressibility when it isn't realistic.

Comment: Sorry to heat that, because assuming it is incompressible has provided the basis for successfully and accurately designing and operating liquid systems for hundreds of years.

Comment: There are many physical processes that cannot be accurately modeled with an assumption of incompressibility.

Comment: So.  This isn't one of them, unless the fluid really does have a high degree of compressibility like a gas.  But why are you limiting yourself to just the incompressibility assumption.  Why not also include the viscoelastic behavior of ordinary liquids?  If you are ever going to be competent at applying fluid dynamics to the real world, you need to develop some judgment on what are and are not reasonable assumptions for your system at hand.  Otherwise you'll be wasting tons of your valuable time and you employers money chasing that last decimal place.

Comment: Ya I hear ya, but my strategy is to develop physical intuition and physical understanding down to the molecular level, then use that intuition and understanding to build models of processes (that occur near the molecular level) that have never had a successful model before.   The vertical tube example is just a tool to use for understanding pressure fields better.

Comment: Easy there.  I haven't seen a real answer yet, or anything that even approaches a real answer.  I'm not going to upvote a non-answer.

Comment: Pressure at the top is atmospheric, at the bottom is atmospheric. The mass flow has to be constant across the pipe. How could there possibly be a gradient? Gravity balances with axial viscous force at every point. The long, overcomplicated wording made me think there was a real question here. There’s not.

Comment: Ya know, it just hit me.  Have you been focusing specifically on cases in which the downward volumetric flow rate is very low so that the frictional viscous drag is not sufficient to balance the weight of the fluid (and both ends of the tube area open to the atmosphere)?  If not, forget I asked.

Comment: The is a bottom at $-\infty$

Comment: I submit that, even in the case where the fluid is compressible, if the mass flow rate is such that the viscous drag is precisely in balance with the weight of the fluid, the Navier Stokes equations will yield an exact solution in which both the static pressure and the fluid density are constant along the length of the tube.

Comment: @ChetMiller I edited my answer. Hope it proves it. Regardless, the op is editing the question and asking your feedback about things and saying above that he does not have enough points to reply to you here. Fyi

Answer (score 0):

Summary: I show why the only possible pressure gradient can be a constant gradient. And that neither end can be above atmospheric. Therefore by contradiction there cannot be a pressure gradient. That’s toward the bottom. Most of the rest is to gain intuitive understanding.

---

Overall Intuition:

A volume of gas that does not have any external pressure on it will expand to fill all available space. A volume of liquid that does not have any pressure on it will expand to its zero-pressure specific volume, $v_{0*}$. (We don’t generally think of liquids as being compressible because they are not *very* compressible, but they are.)

If a liquid is confined at the bottom, then the fluid layer on the bottom is confined and faces the pressure of the weight of the liquid above it. It cannot expand downward even the tiny amount necessary to achieve the $v_{0*}$ volume. This layer of liquid is confined under pressure.

However if the bottom is removed, the entire volume of liquid is free to expand the tiny amount necessary for the full height of it to be at $v_{0*}$.

The only possible resistance to the expansion of the whole column is the viscous sheer forces of flow in the tube. But because the compression is only ~$0.01$%, the expansion of a $10m$ tube of liquid will only be one millimeter. This will happen quickly without generating enough velocity for viscous forces to hamper it (Viscous force is an increasing function of velocity, and $F_{\mu}(0)=0$).

All of this is true regardless of whether and how much the fluid is flowing. It is still a column of fluid and will require external net pressure to be compressed. If a bottom is provided, then the weight provides the pressure from above to compress it and the container bottom provides the pressure from below and the tube sides provide pressure from the sides. Barring force from all directions, the liquid can expand and will not have any pressure.

---

Specifics:

You may still be thinking that there could be a gradient and *dynamics* somehow. But consider each layer as below.

If we consider a small control mass of fluid of height $L_z$ inside the tube (a control volume is a defined section of space where mass can move into and/or out of the control volume; a control mass is a quantity of actual, specific fluid particles), then it will be flowing down the tube due to gravity at velocity $v$, with a viscous resistance force per unit length $f_{\mu}=\frac{F_{\mu}}{h}$, and will be governed by:

$$F= f_{\mu}(v) L_z + L_z \frac{dp}{dz} - gA \rho L_z = ma=0$$

**Note this is true for all $z$**. That implies $v$ is constant. And therefore $ \frac{dp}{dz}$ is constant (because both $gA \rho $ and  $f_{\mu}(v) $ are constant; true even for $a \neq 0$).

All this means that the only possible pressure gradient is a constant pressure gradient. If we have a constant pressure gradient then either the top layer or bottom layer or both is above atmospheric. If, $wlog$, the bottom layer is above atmospheric, then it will expand against the air until it is at $v_{0*}$ and no longer be so, which shows by contradiction there could not have been a gradient. If neither end can be above atmospheric and the only possible pressure gradient is constant, then there cannot be a pressure gradient.

More intuitively, the fluid layer at each end can expand instantly, and the layer next to it can also expand pushing the layer below it the tiny amount necessary, etc. Even the middle layer in the center of the tube can expand and push half the liquid far enough to be able to expand, because the needed displacement is so low and flow only resists velocity.